# transfer state not work in angular 17 and APIs are calling from client side

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-transfer-state

My project was on angular 15 version and SSR and transfer state was working fine and APIs called from server side
but after migrate to angular 17 transfer state not work and same APIs are called in client

```
export const HOME = makeStateKey('home');
getHomeSections(forMobile: string):Observable<HomeSection[]>{
return this.dataStateService.checkAndGetData(HOME,
  this.http.get<ApiResponse<HomeSection[]>>(`core/Home`, {params: {forMobile}}).pipe(map(
    res => {
      return res.result;
    }
  ))
);
```

}

```
  checkAndGetData(key: string & { __not_a_string: never; __value_type?: void }, getDataObservable: Observable<any>, defaultValue: any = []) {
if (this.transferState.hasKey(key)) {
  return of(this.transferState.get(key, defaultValue));
} else {
  return getDataObservable.pipe(
    tap((data) => {
      if (this.isServer) {
        this.transferState.set(key, data);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

}

Comment: remove all of the transfer state codes for get requests. angular handle these issues with hydration.

Comment: how can i do it
you mean no need to use transfer state ?

Comment: Like @MojtabaNejadPoorEsmaeili said before, transfer state is no longer needed with Angular 17 new hydration. Can you please provide us your server.ts code also ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this operator in RxJS. It saves the data to the cache on the server and also runs the query on the Frontend to revalidate the fresh data. To disable this refresh use `of(transferState.get<T>(stateKey, {} as T))` if the key is found.

```js
export const handleServerState = <T>(
  transferState: TransferState,
  stateKey: StateKey<T>,
  isServer: boolean,
): ((source$: Observable<T>) => Observable<T>) => {
  return (source$: Observable<T>) => {
    if (isServer) {
      return source$.pipe(tap(data => transferState.set(stateKey, data)))
    }

    if (transferState.hasKey(stateKey)) {
      return source$.pipe(
        startWith(transferState.get<T>(stateKey, {} as T)),
        tap(() => transferState.remove(stateKey)),
      )
    }

    return source$
  }
}
```

The usage is like this:

```js
const HOME_SECTION_STATE_KEY = makeStateKey<ApiResponse<HomeSection[]>>('HOME_SECTION_STATE_KEY')

...

this.http.get('...').pipe(
  handleServerState(this.transferState, HOME_SECTION_STATE_KEY, isPlatformServer(this.platformId))
)
```